# inner join with extra conditions

Tags: sql, left-join

I'm trying to setup a rating app for images. I want to display the images that haven't been rated by the current logged user.

This covers two tables, I've successfully joined the tables but the extra conditions:

1. must be an image
2. exclude any images that have already been rated by the current user are not working.

It's displaying the results as if the 2 AND conditions aren't there at all.

```
SELECT 
   ver_data_media.id, ver_data_media.value, ver_data_media.ref, 
   ver_data_media.type, ver_data_rating.a
FROM 
   ver_data_media
LEFT JOIN 
   ver_data_rating ON ver_data_media.ref = ver_data_rating.a
                   AND ver_data_media.type = 'image'
                   AND ver_data_rating.a != $current_user->ID
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks Frank.

Comment: Can you show us your two table schema, sample data and expected output please?

Comment: working on getting the schema now

Comment: Please take a look at the sample table schema, data and results provided in the update section of my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try the following? Choose the records for current user, then show images where rating is null/empty... perhaps. It is better if you had showed us your table schema thouhg..for a more effective answer.

```
SELECT ver_data_media.id, ver_data_media.value, 
ver_data_media.ref, ver_data_media.type, ver_data_rating.a
FROM ver_data_media
LEFT JOIN ver_data_rating
ON ver_data_media.ref = ver_data_rating.a
WHERE ver_data_media.type = 'image'
AND ver_data_rating.a is null
AND id = $current_user -- shouldn't this be like userid = $current_user, 
                        -- where is this ID coming from? what is its relation to this table?
```

Otherwise the most possible issue would be the **data you are validating aren't the same type**, `ver_data_rating.a != $current_user->ID` on this line.
I guess the best suggestion would be to **cast** one data type into both `ver_Data_rating.a` and `$current_user`.

For e.g. you may use either of the following to test out.

- `CAST(ver_data_rating.a AS INT) != CAST($current_user as INT)`
- `CAST(ver_data_rating.a AS INT) <> = CAST($current_user as INT)`

---

### UPDATE: with Recommended Table Schema and sample query

It seems like, the way your query connects, the relationships really do have some issue. Please take a look at this sample and let us know your results. I have listed two ways to get the **unrated** `media records` from media table for a particular user/user online. A variable is used to store the user id.

**[SQLFIDDLE DEMONSTRATION](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ccc38/1)**

Sample data:

```
-- media table
ID  VALUE   REF     TYPE
1   300     15      image
2   100     25      art
3   500     35      cartoon
4   200     35      image
5   100     25      image
6   200     15      image
7   400     15      image
8   250     15      image
9   500     15      image
10  180     15      art

-- rating table
RID     MID     UID     SOMETHING
100     1       15      xyz
101     2       25      abc
102     5       25      efg
103     3       35      abc
```

Step by step Queries:

```
set @user_id:=15;

-- find all media records for @user, type image
select * from media
where ref = @user_id
and type = 'image'
;

-- find all rated reords for @user
select mid from rating
 where uid = @user_id
;

-- media records that needs to be rated by @user
-- using IN clause
select * from media
where id not in 
(select mid from rating
 where uid = @user_id)
and type = 'image'
and ref = @user_id
;

-- media records that needs to be rated by @user
-- using INNER JOIN
select m.*
from media m
inner join (
select mid from rating
 where uid = @user_id) as x
on m.id <> x.mid
and m.type = 'image'
and m.ref = @user_id
;
```

Results for each step by step query above:

```
ID  VALUE   REF     TYPE
1   300     15      image
6   200     15      image
7   400     15      image
8   250     15      image
9   500     15      image
```

rated record ids from rating table under user = 15, type = image

```
MID
1
```

using IN clause : unrated media records for user = 15, type = image`

```
ID  VALUE   REF     TYPE
6   200     15      image
7   400     15      image
8   250     15      image
9   500     15      image
```

using INNER JOIN : unrated media records for user = 15, type = image

```
ID  VALUE   REF     TYPE
6   200     15      image
7   400     15      image
8   250     15      image
9   500     15      image
```

Comment: Well that is just about the best answer I've ever seen to anything.

It worked, thanks buddy.

Comment: @frankstuner I am glad you got it worked :-)  here is a good article that I like to share on [`joins`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins) hope that helps you along the journey of database design. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

left join is basically short for left outer join. You need to separate your additional filters outside of the JOIN conditions and into the WHERE clause. Your query is saying get me all records from ver_data_media. Along with that, give me ver_data_ratings that match my condition or no ver_data_ratings otherwise. Hard to translate to english :)  I also think, the columns you're comparing aren't right or should be renamed.

Try this...

```
SELECT ver_data_media.id, ver_data_media.value, ver_data_media.ref, ver_data_media.type, ver_data_rating.a
FROM ver_data_media
LEFT OUTER JOIN ver_data_rating
ON ver_data_media.id= ver_data_rating.media_id
WHERE ver_data_media.type = 'image'
AND ver_data_rating.user_id <> $current_user->ID
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, I tried that code but it returned nothing, a blank page. When I was trying stuff originally whenever I added a where clause to the join it returned a blank white page with nothing in the source.

Comment: Do you want ver_data_media records if there are no matching ratings?

Comment: yep kicko that's correct. To be specific, I want the records that have the type="image" and are not already in the rating table with the current logged users id (have not already been rated by this user.)

Comment: last effort edit above. As @bonCodigo pointed out. The columns you're comparing don't look right or their names are not very clear. the query above offers suggested names.

Comment: @frankstuner according to your comment, you do not have records that aren't rated in the rating table. So you do not have to check this rating id in the rating table to find out un-entered records. You may want to get all records for this user then filter out the ones that are rated. Take the rest. Please help us to help you by showing the table schema.